# GUI / report for Selenium / Maven test failures

Tags: selenium-webdriver, java, maven, intellij

I've got testers starting to work with Selenium / Maven / Java / IntelliJ Idea. Does anyone know if a way I can generate a GUI report of a test's results after it has been complete? Only need to display the report in single test cases.

I need this report to be handed back to the developers for bug fixes and to be attached to tickets in project management tools.

Currently working on creating my own solution but was wondering if any knew of a plugin to do this, or assist with this.

---

Not sure why this was downvoted. Current progress is below
[image]

Answer (score 1):

There are plenty. For example, if integrating with Jenkins, there's the [Selenium HTML Report](https://plugins.jenkins.io/seleniumhtmlreport/) which allows you to drill down in the summary as well.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

As per my experience in a professional automation testing services organization, I will suggest you to use one of the below tools as per your current configuration i.e. Selenium / Maven / Java / IntelliJ Idea -

1. TestNG - It is an automation testing framework which provides
   default HTML reports.
2. Extent Reports - This report besides a    consolidated execution report, also provides a pie chart    representation of your executed
   test cases, screen shots of failed    test cases and test stepwise
   detailed logging. **This will suit best to you as
   per your requirement of sharing a    consolidated executed list of
   test cases to developers and attaching    the results in project
   management tools.**
3. Allure reporting - This    also works like Extent report. Please find Sample report in this    [link](http://allure-reporting.herokuapp.com/index.html#/features).
4. You can convert your execution results into Excel or    spreadsheet format as well by using Apache POI tool. It is a just a jar file or a plugin which you can add into your POM.xml

Note:- If you use Jenkins as CI tool, you can use plugins like - Selenium HTML report.